# mysql select - how to retrieve a result for threaded/nested messages?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, select, nested, hierarchical-data

I'm creating a threaded message board and I'm trying to keep it simple.  There's a message table, and then a replies table that has an 'reply_id' field that can be null to indicate a top level response, or a value that indicates a threaded response.

I'm a bit confused on how to do a SELECT call on this type of table though?

```
Reply
-id (every reply gets a unique id)
-message_id (the message it is replying to)
-reply_id (the id of the reply it may be replying to - for threading)
-reply
```

I know this can be a complex problem, especially for performance, but I'm really just looking for the most basic solution to this.

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the naive "textbook" way of storing trees, i.e. store a reference to the immediate parent.  This design is called **Adjacency List**.  There are other solutions:

- **Path Enumeration**, where you store in each node of the tree a string encoding all its direct ancestors.
- **Nested Sets**, a clever approach by Joe Celko where you use two numeric values per node to bound all its descendants.
- **Closure Table** (or Adjacency Relation), where you use a separate table to list every ancestor-descendant pair.

See my response to "[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree#192462)" for references and examples of the Closure Table design.

Comment: I like the Closure Table method, as well.